# Grails custom validator error

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, grails-2.0

I use Grails 2.3.7.
My domain class Product:

```
class Product {
    static belongsTo = [firmData: Firm_data]

    String name
    SectorType sectorType
    Measure measure
    Float soldProducts
    Float percentOfIncome
    Float percentOfExpense

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false, unique: 'firmData'
        percentOfIncome (range: 0..100, validator: {value, object ->
            def products = Product.findAllByFirmData(object.firmData)
            def sumOfIncome = (products?.percentOfIncome?.sum() ?: 0) + object.percentOfIncome
            print sumOfIncome
            return (sumOfIncome <= 100)
        })
        percentOfExpense (range: 0..100, validator: {value, object ->
            def products = Product.findAllByFirmData(object.firmData)
            def sumOfExpense = (products?.percentOfExpense?.sum() ?: 0) + object.percentOfExpense
            print sumOfExpense
            return (sumOfExpense <= 100)
        })
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that next added `Product`, which also belongs to specified `Firm_data firmData` won't exceed value 100 (when sum up all instances of product for selected Firm_data) on values: `percentOfIncome` or `percentOfExpense`.

I've got an error when trying to add initial data while executing Bootstrap:

```
14:14:21,127 ERROR AssertionFailure: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.example.Product entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1709)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:113)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternalWithExpressions(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:401)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:79)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.call(GormStaticApi.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:59)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.example.Product$__clinit__closure1_closure2.doCall(Product.groovy:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at com.example.Product$__clinit__closure1_closure2.call(Product.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ValidatorConstraint.processValidate(ValidatorConstraint.java:85)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:960)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:209)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:79)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:65)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
at com.example.Product.validate(Product.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:362)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:327)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreInsert(ClosureEventListener.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:79)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.publishEvent(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:159)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:120)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.performSaveOrReplicate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:246)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:104)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:195)
at com.example.Product.save(Product.groovy)
at com.example.Product$save.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.example.ProductService.$tt__createTestProducts(ProductService.groovy:21)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.doCall(ProductService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.call(ProductService.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.call(ProductService.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:62)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:59)
at com.example.ProductService.createTestProducts(ProductService.groovy)
at com.example.ProductService$createTestProducts.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:960)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:75)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14:14:21,141 ERROR GrailsContextLoader: Error initializing the application: null id in com.example.Product entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.example.Product entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1709)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:113)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternalWithExpressions(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:73)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:401)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:79)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.call(GormStaticApi.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:59)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.example.Product$__clinit__closure1_closure2.doCall(Product.groovy:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at com.example.Product$__clinit__closure1_closure2.call(Product.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ValidatorConstraint.processValidate(ValidatorConstraint.java:85)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:960)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:209)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:79)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:65)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
at com.example.Product.validate(Product.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:362)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:327)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreInsert(ClosureEventListener.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:79)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.publishEvent(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:159)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:120)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.performSaveOrReplicate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:246)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:104)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(SavePersistentMethod.java:58)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.SavePersistentMethod.performSave(SavePersistentMethod.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:215)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:195)
at com.example.Product.save(Product.groovy)
at com.example.Product$save.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.example.ProductService.$tt__createTestProducts(ProductService.groovy:21)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.doCall(ProductService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.call(ProductService.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at com.example.ProductService$_createTestProducts_closure1.call(ProductService.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:62)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:59)
at com.example.ProductService.createTestProducts(ProductService.groovy)
at com.example.ProductService$createTestProducts.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:20)
[...]
```

It crashes at line `def products = Product.findAllByFirmData(object.firmData)`.

How to fix it? Why does it occur?

Comment: Please, add the Bootstrap code where you are adding data

Comment: I used simple `(new Product(mapWithAllParameters)).save()`, but I've already found a solution for this issue. Check my answer with flushMode.

Comment: Yes. I see. But normally you don't need to do that. It's seems you are breaking the transactional flow with something.

Comment: Yes, I'm breaking it in my custom validator. If you know any cleaner way to obtain the same result I'll be happy to know it and set as the answer.

Comment: I was thinking about managing a transaction for saving each object, but your solution seems easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that validators are executed so often. The solution:

`import org.hibernate.FlushMode`

and than in custom validator change FlushMode during retrieving data from db, (to avoid unneccessary flushing changes):

```
percentOfIncome (range: 0..100, validator: {value, object ->
    def products = Product.findAllByFirmData(object.firmData, [flushMode: FlushMode.MANUAL] )
    def sumOfIncome = (products?.percentOfIncome?.sum() ?: 0) + object.percentOfIncome
    return (sumOfIncome <= 100)
        })
```